# Github checks API vs check runs vs check suites

Tags: github-api, github-actions

I want to understand Github Checks API so that I can use them to retrieve data. On following Github documentation https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-checks-api I am able to derive that check runs are associated with the sha of the change and at each commit on branch check suite is created. Checks API helps in getting all this information. But I want more clarity on three of them in terms of differences. Can anyone please explain these three terms using simple example and terms?

Comment: What three terms exactly? Are you asking about the difference between the status and checks APIs?

Comment: @Nickofthyme check API, check runs and check suites.. sort of difference in three of these and if any example to differentiate them.

Answer (score 52):

So, first of all, the GitHub [**Commit Statuses** API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses?apiVersion=2022-11-28) is separate from the GitHub
[**Checks** API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks) (includes suites & runs), so let's look at them individually first then I'll explain the differences.

Before we get into it, I want to differentiate a **PR Check** from a **Check Run**, to avoid confusion. A **PR Check** describes the current state (trying not to say status here ) of a given job or task running in CI or elsewhere on a specific PR commit. These can be created via *either* a **Commit Status** or a **Check Run**. All the items in the pink box below are **PR Checks**, notice the *Hide all checks* button.

[image: example-pull-request-checks-from-react-github-repo]

## GitHub statuses - [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses)

I see this as the simple, all-purpose API for reporting **PR Checks** for a given commit. It's easy and doesn't require jumping through hoops to just display a simple result of a **PR Check** for a given commit. This API also came before the check API so it's a little less powerful.

### Pros

- Simple and easy API
- Simple relation with `context` as the identifier.
- Can have a *fully* customizable text description on the **PR Checks** UI.
- You can create statuses as a user with a [Personal Access Token (aka PAT)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) without needing to create a [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps), though does work with [GitHub Apps](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps) too!

### Cons

- Limited `status` options, only allow `error`, `failure`, `pending`, `success`, no `conclusion` subset option to define completed jobs like **Check Runs**.
- No concept of job timing or duration.
- No grouping of statuses, like **Check Runs** are grouped into **Check Suites** by their [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps)
- No annotations
- No detailed `output` logs. This is not too important as you could just link to the URL where the actual **PR Check** was run such as in CircleCI, Jenkins, etc. But the user is not always authorized to view these runs so the output could be helpful for open source repos that have non-public CI.

## GitHub Checks - [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks)

The **Checks** API is the latest and greatest tool for displaying task results on commits, which can *essentially* do everything the **Commit Statuses** API can do and more. **Check Runs** belong to one **Check Suite**, one **Check Suite** can have many **Check Runs**. You can only have one **Check suite** per commit (i.e. `head_sha`) per [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps), attempting to create another for a given App will just return the previously created **Check Suite**. Thus, a new **Check Run** is automatically assigned to the **Check Suite** based on the authenticated [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps), you cannot manually assign Run to Suites.

Contrary to statuses, Check runs are identified by an auto-generated `check_run_id` and not a `context` string.

I haven't touched too much on the **Check Suites** [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/suites) because they are really just a grouping of **Check Runs** which is pretty self-explanatory and they don't affect any of the **PR Checks** UI, only the grouping of **Check Runs** in the checks tab. One thing to note is that by default you can [create a **Check Run**](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs#create-a-check-run) without having to first create a **Check suite** and GitHub will just create a new **Check Suite** for you.

### Pros

- Greater granularity of `status`/`conclusion` for a run.
- A lot of power to display the result of a **PR Check**.
- Can provide run context via output summary in Markdown.
- Can create annotations for specific lines of code to add information about the analysis performed, like linting error for a given line of code. These will show up in the PR files tab UI similar to PR code comments as well as in the PR Checks tab with any other **Check Run** output.
- Has time awareness to report on durations automatically with little effort.

### Cons

- A little more complicated API and relationships to manage.
- Part of the description in the PR UI is auto-generated based on the `status` `conclusion` and duration of the check run task.
- Cannot be *created* via a user [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), must be created from an authenticated [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps). Read access to this API does **not** require authenticating as a [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps).

> One edge case you likely won't come across but is good to know: If you are creating a new **Check Run** with the exact same `name` of an existing check run under the same authenticated app. The resulting behavior is a little strange but doing this will create the new **Check Run** under the same name, but will **not** delete the existing **Check Run**. However, the **Check Suite** will not see or link to the existing **Check Run**, even in the PR UI. BUT!! If you change the `name` of either such that the runs now have unique `name`s, it will be linked up again. It seems GitHub just does a sort by date and then filters by unique names when looking up **Check Runs** in a **Check Suite**. This does not apply with identical `names` from different authenticated apps.

## Comparisons

Below is a mapping of sorts to compare similar options between the **Commit Statuses** API and the **Check Runs** API. They are not exactly 1:1 but similar.

| **Commit Status** | **Check Run** | Option Desciption |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `sha` | `head_sha` | These are equivalent with the minor exception that the **Commit Status** is linked to the `sha` directly, whereas the `head_sha` is linked to the **Check Suite** that the **Check Run** belongs to. |
| `context` | `name` | The `context` is used as an identifier but both define the title of the **PR Check** in the PR UI. Because **Check Runs** are tracked by the `check_run_id` the `name` option may change without creating a new **Check Run**. This is ***not*** the case for `context`, changing the `context` will always create a new **Commit Status**. You may not have duplicate `names` for **Check Runs** created with the same [GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/getting-started-with-apps/about-apps), see note above. |
| `context`* | `external_id` | The `external_id` is meant for keeping track of **Check Runs** without having to store ids or always keep the `name` constant. This is only somewhat similar to the `context` option but only for the purpose of identifying the **Check Run**. |
| `description` | `output.title` | The main difference here is that `description` gives you the full space to work with, where `output.title` will be displayed after the auto-generated status string. |
| `target_url` | `details_url` | These are somewhat equivalent, the first difference is that `target_url` will not show unless defined whereas `details_url` will default to the check run URL in the PR UI. The other difference is the **Check Runs** `Details` button on the **PR Checks** UI will *always* link the the **Checks** page which will present a link to the `details_url` if defined. |
| `state` | `status` | These are very similar but have slightly different allowed values but effectively appear the same in the PR UI. |
| N/A | `conclusion` | This just shows the increased power of the **PR Checks** API where you have more granular control over the **PR Check** status, though not a big difference in the UI, see example variations below. |
| N/A | `started_at` | No comparable option for **Commit Statuses**. |
| N/A | `completed_at` | No comparable option for **Commit Statuses**. |
| N/A | `actions` | No comparable option for **Commit Statuses**. |
| N/A | `output` | No comparable option for **Commit Statuses**. |
| N/A | `output.annotations` | No comparable option for **Commit Statuses**. |

> * Only somewhat similar, not a direct equivalent.

### PR Checks UI Component mappings

I've taken a simple **PR Check** and highlighted the differences between the elements of the UI between the **Commit Status** API and the **Check Runs** API. Very similar but slight differences.

[image: PR checks UI breakdown]

Below are example variations to relate the options to their impact on the
**PR Checks** UI.

#### Commit status variations

[image: commit status variants in the PR UI]

#### Check Run variations

[image: check run variants in the PR UI]

> If a check run is in an incomplete state for more than 14 days, then the **Check Run's** `conclusion` becomes `stale`. Only GitHub can mark **Check Runs** as `stale`.

### Checks Tab in PR UI

The Checks Tab in the PR UI will display all created **Check Suites** and their child **Check Runs** and allows you to set the `output` option to control the content of this page. This page would also show `images` and `annotations` if you defined those too.

[image: Check tab example]

---

One final note: You cannot *DELETE* any **Commit Status**, **Check Run** or **Check Suite** once created, only updating is allowed. With these statuses being so ephemeral this is not that big of a deal but in case you were wondering.

---

### Update (6/21/2022)

I found two more quirks to explain. First, the `details_url` for **Check Runs** does **not** set the value of the `Details` button, instead the `Details` button actually always redirects to the **Checks** page which has a link to the `details_url` if defined.

Second, once a **Check Run** `status` is set to `'completed'`, there is not way to un-complete the **Check run**. But you can get around this by creating a new **Check Run** with the same `name` and set that `status` to something other than `'completed'`. See this edge case with duplicate-`name`d **Check Runs** explained above in detail.

---

### Update (6/29/2022)

As mentioned above, the **Check Runs** API keeps track of the duration of the run. It is important to note that the `started_at` time is set only once whenever a check run is created, regardless of the defined `status`. For example, if I trigger a CI build and set all jobs `status` to `queued`, the jobs run duration will be inaccurate. A good way to fix this is to always set the `started_at` time whenever you set the `status` to `in_progress`. Something as simple as `const started_at = new Date().toISOString()` (javascript) will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @Nickofthyme for the answer. This made the comparison quite simple.

Comment: An exceptional answer. Thank you!